# Is it possible to return a container from a loop when the container is used by an iterator?

Tags: rust

I have an iterator to a `BufReader` and want to return a `BufReader`. This example is simple enough that it would be suitable to just use `return`, but the real code structure is more complex and `return` is not suitable:

```
fn f() -> Result<Vec<i32>, &'static str> {
    let ret = vec![1, 2, 3];

    for i in ret.iter() {
        if *i == 2 {
            return Ok(ret);
        }
    }
    Err("no element")
}
```

This compiles with the error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `ret` because it is borrowed
   |
11 |     for i in ret.iter() {
   |              --- borrow of `ret` occurs here
12 |         if *i == 2 {
13 |             return Ok(ret);
   |                       ^^^ move out of `ret` occurs here
```

Why is this an error if all references are local? Is it really important that the references still exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently unsupported by the borrowchecker, but it would not be idiomatic anyway. The idiomatic solution is

```
if ret.contains(&2) {
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

Since your real code is `BufReader`, I'll assume you mean the iterator returned by the [`bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.bytes) method. In that case, the idiomatic solution would instead be a variant of the following.

```
if ret.bytes().any(|b| b == Ok(2)) {
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this an error if all references are local?

Well, not exactly. The `iter()` call looks like it does not borrow anything but it is. The signature is `fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T>`. When you call `ret.iter()`, you are actually calling `iter(&ret)` which is immutably borrowing `ret`. That borrow will be valid until the scope of the `for` loop, which is itself syntactic sugar over a `while` loop until the iterator's `next` function no longer returns a value.